# How can I setup Tomcat to serve pre compressed javascript files?

Tags: javascript, tomcat, gzip

I have all JS files pre compressed in my web app (.js.gz) and want to make Tomcat to serve those whenever JS files are requested and the browser is able to handle compressed JS. 
I tried to use the .js.gz file names in the HTML script tag, however, the browser (FF67 in this case) appears unable to recognize the downloaded files as pre compressed and complains about the first character of the file being invalid. Changing the type within the script tag to "application/x-gzip" doesn't help.

My gut feeling is that the solution lies within the Tomcat config (or probably just within the web.xml of my web app) and should be pretty straightforward yet I'm having a hard time coming up with a decent idea. Any help out there?

Comment: Why do you compress JS files by yourself?

Comment: I'm using GWT which can be setup to create gzip'ed JS files during build, so, those files are already there.